# Install bower packages on team services build

Tags: visual-studio, build, bower, azure-devops

So i have a build definition on my team services project

My source code in the repo does not include the packages loaded via bower however I do have a bower.json file in the solution.

I want my bower task in the build to load my bower packages into the project and then to be included in the artifact drop output

My build does run the bower task but I dont see the output packages in the destination folder

Any help would be great

This is my build definition for bower[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pwxC.png)

I assumed that the bower task would restore all the packages to the build maybe I have not ordered the task correctly?

Comment: How does your bower task looks like? Which VSTS task are you using, and with what parameters?

Comment: What's detail of your build definition? Do you use Copy Files to copy files to artifact folder and use Publish Artifact step to publish artifact files from artifact folder to drop folder?

Comment: I have added above an image to the build def

Comment: Yes I use a copy files to  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)

Comment: Please note that the task you're using is not an out-of-the-box VSTS task, but a 3rd party task from the marketplace. You might get a better answer if you use the [support channel](https://github.com/touchifyapp/vsts-bower/issues) for this extension as mentioned in the marketplace entry.

Comment: Thanks I have added a post to the support channel as well. Is there another way of achieving this that you know?

Comment: I always put the bower_components folder under version control, do make my build not dependent on external resources. While packages for other package management systems, like npm or NuGet, can be cached on a lokal server to get avoid of this dependency, Bower packages simply pull files from external repositories. Once this repository is down your build will no longer work.

Comment: Can you share the build logs?

Comment: @user1488692 Does destination folder means artifact folder (a folder) or source folder? What's the bower CLI location of bower install step? Is that path existing? If not, you need to add npm step (arguments: bower) before bower install step.

Comment: @user1488692 Do you solve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a test to output the bower packages to drop folder with **hosted build agent**, you can check my steps below and test on your side:

1. In my test, I just created a bower.json file to install jquery packages. From the build log, we can see the the jquery packages are instlled in folder *bower_components*. Folder *bower_components* is created in `$(build.sourcesdirectory)` by default.

[image]

2. So I just create another `Copy Files` task, and copy folder *bower_components* to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`.

[image]

3. Then you'll see folder *bower_components* will be in drop folder:

[image]